# What happens if I never clean up Elasticsearch tasks?

Tags: elasticsearch

The [update by query docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-task-api) says that with `wait_for_completion=false` a task will get created, to track progress, and that the task api should be used clean up the tasks afterwards.

What is the consequence of never cleaning up these old tasks, or doing so very infrequently?  Is the cost only the disk space these task files take up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's not a big deal if you don't cleanup those tasks immediately. The `.tasks` index usually has one primary shard, which allows you to spawn up to 2B tasks (= 2^31, i.e. maximum number of docs per shard) before getting into trouble.

If you use them to keep track of your tasks, it's better to clean them up once they are done, otherwise you might end up with a mess of finished task documents that are not easy to sort out.

That can also be taken care of by a simple cron job that periodically runs

```
DELETE .tasks/_delete_by_query?q=*
```